# How can I iterate over a delimited string, accumulating state from previous iterations without explicitly tracking the state?

Tags: rust

I want to produce an iterator over a delimited string such that each substring separated by the delimiter is returned on each iteration with the substring from the previous iteration, including the delimiter.

For example, given the string `"ab:cde:fg"`, the iterator should return the following:

1. `"ab"`
2. `"ab:cde"`
3. `"ab:cde:fg"`

**Simple Solution**

A simple solution is to just iterate over collection returned from splitting on the delimiter, keeping track of the previous path:

```rust
let mut state = String::new();
for part in "ab:cde:fg".split(':') {
    if !state.is_empty() {
        state.push_str(":");
    }
    state.push_str(part);
    dbg!(&state);
}
```

The downside here is the need to explicitly keep track of the state with an extra mutable variable.

**Using `scan`**

I thought `scan` could be used to hide the state:

```rust
    "ab:cde:fg"
        .split(":")
        .scan(String::new(), |state, x| {
            if !state.is_empty() {
                state.push_str(":");
            }
            state.push_str(x);
            Some(&state)
        })
        .for_each(|x| { dbg!(x); });
```

However, this fails with the error:

> cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements

What is the problem with the `scan` version and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let us cheat and get your code to compile, so that we can inspect the issue at hand. We can do so by cloning the `state`. Also, let's add some debug message:

```
fn main() -> () {
    "ab:cde:fg"
        .split(":")
        .scan(String::new(), |state, x| {  // (1)
            if !state.is_empty() {
                state.push_str(":");
            }
            state.push_str(x);
            eprintln!(">>> scan with {} {}", state, x);
            Some(state.clone())
        })
        .for_each(|x| {                    // (2)
            dbg!(x);
        });
}
```

This [results in the following output](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9273f7b5d32ed92b51850ade3fcc3c57):

```
scan with ab ab
[src/main.rs:13] x = "ab"
scan with ab:cde cde
[src/main.rs:13] x = "ab:cde"
scan with ab:cde:fg fg
[src/main.rs:13] x = "ab:cde:fg"
```

Note how the `eprintln!` and `dbg!` outputs are interleaved? [That's the result of `Iterator`'s laziness](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#laziness). However, in practice, this means that our intermediate `String` is borrowed twice:

- in the anonymous function `|state, x|` in `state` (1)
- in the anonymous function `|x|` in, well, `x`     (2)

However, this would lead to duplicate borrows, even though at least one of them is mutable. The mutable borrow therefore enforces the lifetime of our `String` to be bound to the anonymous function, whereas the latter function still needs an alive `String`. Even if we somehow managed to annotate lifetimes, we would just end up with an invalid borrow in (2), as the value is still borrowed as mutable.

The easy way out is a `clone`. The smarter way out uses `match_indices` and string slices.

Answer (score 4):

Why even build a new string?
You can get the indices of the `:` and use slices to the original string.

```rust
fn main() {
    let test = "ab:cde:fg";

    let strings = test
        .match_indices(":")            // get the positions of the `:`
        .map(|(i, _)| &test[0..i])     // get the string to that position
        .chain(std::iter::once(test)); // let's not forget about the entire string

    for substring in strings {
        println!("{:?}", substring);
    }
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=52b025140a6cc6393b0c8e8faf94cff3))

Comment: Arguably, it would be more idiomatic to use `std::iter::once(test)` instead of `Some(test)` for the entire string, to avoid thinking that there is some `Option` somewhere that I didn't catch.

Comment: Ahh. I didn't find `match_indices`. I felt a bit let down because `find` doesn't offer a starting index, which is the first approach I tried.

Comment: @rodrigo I'm ambivalent on that, especially considering the implementation of `iter::once` delegates to `Option`.

Comment: @Shepmaster the intent is better with `iter::once`, but of course they should generate exactly the same code.

Comment: @Jon: While `find` does not offer a starting index, you can simply do `test[start_index..].find(...)` to get the equivalent behavior. I had a version with `find` ready for publish... but this one with `match_indices` is much better.